# Complete the equality (medium-hard)

Tags: mathematics, formation-of-numbers, calculation-puzzle

1. Complete the equality to make it true:

   `1 1 1 1 1 = 945`
2. Using similar logic, solve for this:

   `1 1 1 1 1 = 80`

Info:

- You should modify only the left side of `=`
- The equation must remain an equality.
- You can use any operator you want, as many parentheses as you like, combinations, decimals, powers and roots of any value etc.
- There is at least 1 guaranteed solution for each

Be creative :)

Comment: combining 1s is possible, such as 11+111?

Comment: yes, it is, if you'd like that

Answer (score 3):

## 1. 945

> $(1+(1+1+1)!)!!\div.\bar{1}=945$, where $!!$ denotes [double factorial](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DoubleFactorial.html). [[Calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(1%2B(1%2B1%2B1)!)!!%2F(0.111...))]

## 2. 80

> $((1+1+1\times 1)!)!\times .\bar{1}=80$.  [[Calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((1%2B1%2B1*1)!)!*(0.111...))]

Comment: you got the idea. Now try without using the dash (vinculum) :D

Answer (score 2):

This was my answer:

## 1. 945

> $((1+1+1+1)!! + 1)!! = 945$

## 2. 80

> $((1+1+1)! + 1 + 1)!!! = 80$, where 8!!! = 8 x 5 x 2